# How to use Apple Localization Glossaries / AppleGlot to translate basic terms in an iPhone App?

Tags: ios, localization, translation

I have an iOS App that Is in english, I am trying to translate it to couple of other common languages , I found that apple is providing Localization Glossaries that are used in iOS and apple apps . But How can I use the Glossaries file that apple provide in dmg format at https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/ with or without using appleglot which can also be downloaded from the above page.

For e.g.: What I want to achieve is . In my existing app there is a term "Enter Passcode" , that is a term also used in iOS. I want to translate it into French and German. Both the translation is available in the DMG files(Glossaries) provided. But how can I extract it with out manually opening each .lg file and searching for the term?

Answer (score 3):

There is a nice [step-by-step instruction](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles/MaintaingYourOwnStringsFiles.html) (see 'Localizing Strings Files Using AppleGlot'). I have just tested it and AppleGlot worked perfectly, translating Main Menu (macOS) from English into French.

Comment: Indeed. The important detail is to use the "-w" option with the `appleglot` command.